# Was bedeutet "todunglücklich" genau?

Tags: meaning, phrase, adjective

Ich habe diesen Satz in einer Kurzgeschichte gelesen:

> Er ist todunglücklich!

Was bedeutet es genau?

- Ist er so unglücklich, dass er tot gewesen sollen?
- Ist er so unglücklich, dass es für ihn besser wäre, tot zu sein?
- Er ist unglücklich, da seine Tochter tot ist?
- Er ist traurig, dass seine Tochter tot ist?
- Er war unglücklich sein ganzes Leben lang?

usw.

Answer (score 11):

Es ist nur eine Vermutung von mir, aber ich denke, dass *todunglücklich* als [Elativ](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elativ) zu verstehen ist. Es handelt sich also um eine extreme Steigerung zum normalen *unglücklich*. Als Bedeutung könnte *todunglücklich* folgendermaßen interpretiert werden:

> Er war so unglücklich, dass das Wort *unglücklich* nicht ausreichte, seinen Zustand zu beschreiben.

Vergleiche auch *reich* -> *steinreich* = extrem reich

Answer (score 8):

Es bedeutet, dass er sehr unglücklich ist.

Die Herkunft ist vermutlich das französische "tout".

Vergleiche im Deutschen "totschick" oder "todschick" mit "tout chic" im Französischen.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Französisch ist meine Muttersprache und ich habe niemals "tout chic" gehört oder gelesen. "Très chic" usw. kann man aber hören. Außerdem wird in "tout" das zweite "t" nicht ausgesprochen.

Comment: @ogerard: Il semble qu'il s'agit d'une étymologie vieille pendant l'occupation par Napoléon. Et peut-être, ils ont parlés plutôt des femmes ...

Comment: @ogerard: es gibt viele Ausdrücke französischen Ursprungs, die im Deutschen sehr stark abgewandelt wurden. Schöner Artikel dazu: http://www.schule-in-frankfurt.de/45/45-15.htm (stimmt aber nicht alles - Fisimatenten stammt wohl aus dem Latein) - wenn davon einige Ausdrücke heute in Frankreich nicht (mehr) bekannt sind, muss das noch nichts heißen. Französisch war seinerzeit eine Modesprache wie heute Englisch ... und welcher Engländer kennt schon ein "Handy"? ;)

Comment: @thei: magst du das in Deutsch oder Englisch übersetzen? :)

Comment: @ladybug: thei wrote: it is apparently an old derivation, dating of Napoleon occupation of Germany in early 19th century. It might explain that it does not sound native french to me. Another aspect is that it may have been derived from a feminine version such as "toute chic", where the final "t" sound is heard.

Comment: @thei : deine Erklärung stimmt jetzt mit einem anderen Adjektiv: todsicher! Die Ursprung ist vielleicht nicht "tout" or toute" aber "tout à fait" (ganz, wohl, vollständig). Man sagt noch "Tout à fait sûr, tout à fait chic" für todsicher und todschick.

Comment: Is the link with the French word "tout" just a conjecture, or is there any academic support for it?

Answer (score 6):

It means "very unhappy". In German, like in Dutch (my native language) the prefix "tod" is often used as a superlative:

> todsicher = very sure
>   todmüde = very tired
>   todkrank = very ill

While for "todkrank" there seems to be some relevance in using the word "tod" (If you're very ill you can die), for other words the word "tod" is more farfetched. In Dutch you have for instance

> doodnormaal = very much normal
>   doodgewoon = very common

Answer (score 0):

It is, as already explained in other answers, a superlative. Here *tod* exaggerates the unhappiness.

One way to understand the term, is looking at the adjective, say, *kugelrund*. In that adjective, one uses the noun *Kugel* as the most roundest thing by excellence.

To put it in an abstract way, this superlative is made

> `Noun representing the excellence of the adjective` + `adjective`

This superlative *todunglücklich* is of the same form.